# Add link in preloader text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a preloader in which there are four text animations, I want to add a link on last text animation i.e. on 'View More' text in last text animation and when i click on that link it will redirect me to another page. OR when the loader of four text animations ends, it will redirect me to any other pages or any other index page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Opening Sequence</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <title>Text Opening Sequence with CSS Animations</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Text Opening Sequence with CSS Animations" />



        <style type="text/css">
            /* General Demo Style */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:200,600);
*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



/* Clearfix hack by Nicolas Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Dosis', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

a {
  color: #f0f0f0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Header Style */
.codrops-top {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-size: 0.68em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  line-height: 2.2;
}

.codrops-top a {
  padding: 0 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  display: inline-block;
}

.codrops-top a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

.codrops-top span.right {
  float: right;
}

.codrops-top span.right a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.os-phrases h2 {
  font-family: 'Dosis', 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  letter-spacing: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

.os-phrases h2,
.os-phrases h2 > span {
  height: 100%;
  /* Centering with flexbox */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.os-phrases h2 > span {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.os-phrases h2 > span > span {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.os-phrases h2 > span > span > span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-animation: OpeningSequence 5.2s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: OpeningSequence 5.2s linear forwards;
  animation: OpeningSequence 5.2s linear forwards;
}

.os-phrases h2:nth-child(2) > span > span > span {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.os-phrases h2:nth-child(3) > span > span > span {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 10s;
  animation-delay: 10s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes OpeningSequence {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
    letter-spacing: 80px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    letter-spacing: 14px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  85% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(130px);
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes OpeningSequence {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
    letter-spacing: 80px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    letter-spacing: 14px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  85% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateZ(130px);
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
@keyframes OpeningSequence {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
    letter-spacing: 80px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    letter-spacing: 14px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  85% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateZ(130px);
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
.os-phrases h2:nth-child(4) > span > span > span {
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-animation: FadeIn 4s linear 14s forwards;
  -moz-animation: FadeIn 4s linear 14s forwards;
  animation: FadeIn 4s linear 14s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes FadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes FadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
  }
}
@keyframes FadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
  }
}
/* Bold words */
.os-phrases h2:first-child .word3,
.os-phrases h2:nth-child(2) .word2,
.os-phrases h2:nth-child(4) .word2 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="os-phrases" id="os-phrases">
        <h2>Sometimes it's better</h2>
        <h2>to hide</h2>
        <h2>in order to </h2>   
        <h2>kill evils.<a href="asddff">View More</a> </h2>             
    </div>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lettering.js/0.6.1/jquery.lettering.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $("#os-phrases > h2")
    .css('opacity', 1).lettering( 'words' )
    .children( "span" ).lettering()
    .children( "span" ).lettering();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to add in "animationend" event when the animation of last h2 finish a click event => See this page if you need more information about "animationend" event https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_animationend.asp.

To do so, I add an ID to the last `h2` and put an `on()` event when its animation finish (I used `one()`, 'cause the last animation is triggered 18 times (one for letter=> **jquery.lettering** plugin add a span on every letter), and knowing when the animation of one letter ends is enough, since the animation is the same for all the letters of the last h2.

This is the code:

```
$("#link").one("animationend", function(e){
   $(this).css({"cursor":"pointer"}).on("click", function(){
      window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
   })
});
```

...and this is your beautiful animation! ;)

```js
$("#link").one("animationend", function(e){
  $(this).css({"cursor":"pointer"}).on("click", function(){
    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  })
});

$("#os-phrases > h2")
.css('opacity', 1).lettering( 'words' )
.children( "span" ).lettering()
.children( "span" ).lettering();
```

```css
/* General Demo Style */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:200,600);
*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



/* Clearfix hack by Nicolas Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Dosis', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

a {
  color: #f0f0f0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Header Style */
.codrops-top {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-size: 0.68em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  line-height: 2.2;
}

.codrops-top a {
  padding: 0 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  display: inline-block;
}

.codrops-top a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

.codrops-top span.right {
  float: right;
}

.codrops-top span.right a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.os-phrases h2 {
  font-family: 'Dosis', 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  letter-spacing: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}



.os-phrases h2,
.os-phrases h2 > span {
  height: 100%;
  /* Centering with flexbox */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.os-phrases h2 > span {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.os-phrases h2 > span > span {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.os-phrases h2 > span > span > span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-animation: OpeningSequence 5.2s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: OpeningSequence 5.2s linear forwards;
  animation: OpeningSequence 5.2s linear forwards;
}

.os-phrases h2:nth-child(2) > span > span > span {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.os-phrases h2:nth-child(3) > span > span > span {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 10s;
  animation-delay: 10s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes OpeningSequence {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
    letter-spacing: 80px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    letter-spacing: 14px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  85% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(130px);
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes OpeningSequence {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
    letter-spacing: 80px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    letter-spacing: 14px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  85% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateZ(130px);
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
@keyframes OpeningSequence {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
    letter-spacing: 80px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    letter-spacing: 14px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  85% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateZ(130px);
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
.os-phrases h2:nth-child(4) > span > span > span {
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-animation: FadeIn 4s linear 14s forwards;
  -moz-animation: FadeIn 4s linear 14s forwards;
  animation: FadeIn 4s linear 14s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes FadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes FadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
  }
}
@keyframes FadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 0 50px #fff;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
  }
}
/* Bold words */
.os-phrases h2:first-child .word3,
.os-phrases h2:nth-child(2) .word2,
.os-phrases h2:nth-child(4) .word2 {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lettering.js/0.6.1/jquery.lettering.min.js'></script>


<div class="os-phrases" id="os-phrases">
    <h2>Sometimes it's better</h2>
    <h2>to hide</h2>
    <h2>in order to </h2>   
    <h2 id="link">kill evils.View More </h2>             
</div>
```